# wso2 iot server 3.0.0 device management console not working

Tags: wso2, wso2-iot

When I am trying to open the device management console, it redirect be to the below page and after that nothing would happened when i click on the re-direct button, please suggets, I am using wso2 IOT server 3.0.0 and have started all three modules broker, core and analytics...

[image]

With http below logs printed on console.

[image]

Comment: Do you see any errors in the wso2carbon.log? You can find the logs in wso2iot-3.0.0/<Module>/repository/logs location.

Comment: nothing written in logs all are of 0kb

Comment: with http below are the logs printed on core console

Answer (score 1):

This can happen if `iot.keymanager.host` environment variable is not set properly. By default this is set in `wso2server.bat` file. Check if it's set properly.

Comment: thanks for the reply, i have checked in versions, 3.0.0, Beta2 and beta this environment variable is set in analytics wso2server.bat file only, shall  i need to set it under core module wso2server file also, also one more thing for beta and beta2  version i am able to login on device management console, i am facing this issue with 3.0.0 version only..

Comment: Yes you can add it to other script as well.

Comment: Hi, I have tried by adding the same, but still getting the same issue, request you to please help.

Comment: It should ideally work, but I'm not sure if there are any other issues in beta. Since 3.0.0 GA released now, you can try with that.

Comment: I have tried with 3.0.0 also getting the error while starting Analytics.  [2017-02-01 16:12:27,213] [IoT-Analytics] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.device.mgt.input.adapter.mqtt.util.MQTTAdapterListener} -  error occurred while parsing generating token for the adapter
Unexpected character (<) at position 0.[2017-02-01 16:12:27,244] [IoT-Analytics] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.device.mgt.input.adapter.mqtt.util.MQTTAdapterListener} -  MQTT Exception occurred when starting listener
Bad user name or password (4)

Comment: MQTT error in analytics can pop up if you start the analytics runtime before core. This could happen if you install the sample device types by running the plugins-deployer.xml. When you deploy samples then it starts a listener in analytics which needs to connect to broker. In order to connect it requires core to be up. Either you have to start in the order  ->(broker, core, analytics) or ignore the error if it prints "[2017-02-01 17:17:23,590] [IoT-Analytics]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.device.mgt.input.adapter.mqtt.util.MQTTAdapterListener} -  MQTT Connection successful"

Answer (score 1):

There is an issue when running on Windows and inorder to make it work, we need to start the server with below command.

wso2server.bat -Diot.analytics.host="localhost" -Diot.analytics.https.port="9445" -Dmqtt.broker.host="localhost" -Dmqtt.broker.port="1886" -Diot.core.host="localhost" -Diot.core.https.port="9443" -Diot.keymanager.host="localhost" -Diot.keymanager.https.port="9443" -Diot.gateway.host="localhost" -Diot.gateway.https.port="8243" -Diot.gateway.http.port="8280"

if you are running the above command in an existing pack that you have already 
started then you might need to enable UpdateAPI(set true to EnableUpdateApi) property in webapp-publisher-config.xml in core/repository/conf/etc directory.

Comment: Can you please let me know with which OS we need to run this product as of  now I am able to login in Device management console with windows OS but getting some other error, able to load the login page but when clicked on device management getting some http 500 error "<" token invalid, and because of this new device enroll link not loaded, I am new to these products, please help.

Comment: This works on both linux and windows. But in windows the issue is that the default environment variables was not set. To overcome "http 500 error <" error set set true to EnableUpdateApi property in webapp-publisher-config.xml in core/repository/conf/etc directory and restart. This will republish all the apis again.

Comment: one more thing when I am trying to download virtual fire alarm agent I am getting the error in logs stated: [2017-02-06 23:39:08,336] [] ERROR - VirtualFireAlarmServiceImpl Error occurred when trying to read property file sketch.properties
org.wso2.carbon.device.mgt.common.DeviceManagementException: Error occurred when trying to read property file sketch.properties
        at org.wso2.carbon.device.mgt.iot.virtualfirealarm.service.impl.util.ZipUtil.getSketchArchive(ZipUtil.java:199)

Comment: Caused by: java.io.IOException: Unable to delete file: D:\iot\wso2\iotserver\wso2iot-3.0.0\wso2iot-3.0.0\core\bin\..\repository\resources\sketches\archives\1huxp5813pffl\virtual_firealarm.jks

Comment: when I trying to remove this file manually then getting an error file in use and open in java, and on browser it is showing blank page...