# wso2 3.0 IoT access

Tags: wso2, wso2-iot

I installed wso2 3.0 in windows 7. Also i have installed correctly all prerequisites. I think correctly because i followed tutorials and i din't get any error at all.

Following Running the product part of tutorial i start the server and i don't get any error. 
When i try to open by IP http://192.168.56.235:9446/carbon it shows certificate error. I confirm certificate and after that it shows Error 403-Forbidden.

I have tried three times with three different machines with windows 7,10 and ubuntu 16.10

It's the same result!
What am i missing?

I really appreciate any help!

Thank you

Comment: What are the configurations you've changed? Also can you mention what's the exact certificate error you are getting?

Comment: I haven't change any configuration. The certificate error is that this server certificate is untrusted.

Answer (score 1):

https://192.168.56.235:9446/carbon url is intentionally blocked in the IoTS 3.0.0, This port belongs to mqtt broker and there is no UI capability for this. In order to access IoTS console go to https://IP:**9443**/devicemgt.

In addition, the certificate error that your getting might be related to untrusted certificate that comes by default with the pack, which you need to trust in the local browser before you access the node.

This doc: https://docs.wso2.com/display/IoTS300/Running+the+Product#f86e2494c1ef43a6b6c430abef6d47b8, has the instruction on how to run the product in windows and linux (Please note the environment variables that are passed through when starting it on windows)

Comment: Hi, thanks for your reply. Also i have tried https://IP:9443/devicemgt and http://IP:9763/devicemgt and still nothing. I don't get Error 403-Forbidden but console won't open. Also i have tried different browsers.

Comment: Are you trying this on windows if so then there is an issue in windows that is addressed here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41960899/wso2-iot-server-3-0-0-device-management-console-not-working